# PHP Pushing at the end of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

So I am trying to do the following.
I have an array that contains 12 numbers(months).

```
$array = array();
$array[1] = array();
```

and so on.

Now, I am trying to push numbers into second place like
$array[5][day should be pushed here] trying like so

```
$counter = 0;
while($counter <= $elements)
{
if($something == $something)
{
    $startfrom = 14; //example
    $month = 5; //example
    while($startfrom <= 20)
    {
    array_push($array[$month], $startfrom );
    $startfrom ++;
    }
}
```

But its always returning an error. Like this
 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in F:\xampp\htdocs\NewPassword\Testt\process_info.php on line 27

What I am trying to achieve is that each day goes to its responding month.

Thanks.

Edit:
Nwm, fixed I did biggest rookie mistake I could. I wasn't incrementing counter out of if statement... Thank you APerson.

Comment: Do you increment `$counter` in the outer while loop?

Comment: HOLY LORD, this mistake. I am literally idiot. Oh god lol.
Thanks for the answer well this fixes it.... I still can't believe I missed this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
$counter = 0;
while($counter <= $elements)
{
    if($something == $something)
    {
        $startfrom = 14; //example
        $month = 5; //example
        while($startfrom <= 20)
        {
            array_push($array[$month], $startfrom );
            $startfrom ++;
        }
    $counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to first point out in your referenced code that there's no indication that the outermost while loop is ever terminated  (or even closed properly for that matter ;) so assuming infinite recursion is not actually not the source for PHP's memory leak, I'd encourage you to first:

1. Grab a solid debugger like [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), or (if you've the money) [PHPEd](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm) so that you can profile your scripts and get detailed information about any issues you may have in your code or php settings.
2. If you can affirm via debugging that there's no identifiable issues with your scripts (this is almost always sure to be the problem though), then you can simply increase the `memory_limit` in your `php.ini` file. I'd be weary of going to high here. If you have to surpass 512M then something is seriously wrong.